# Why isn't R or Rscript executing on my Windows box?

Tags: r, windows, rscript

I can't seem to run R.EXE or RSCRIPT.EXE. However, it works if it's in a directory that doesn't contain any spaces. Is this a limitation of the application itself?

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with R.  This is a Windows issue. Place quotes around the full path.

Comment: It doesn't matter. It won't run. Running from the path containing the executable produces the same result.

Comment: It is really just `R` and `RSCRIPT` without the `.exe` extension? Can you show a `dir` of that folder?

Comment: Try running from the directory, but instead of typing `R`  type `.\R`

Comment: When in doubt use tab completion to generate the path

Comment: Sure. http://imgur.com/a/BP112

Comment: Also tried .\r and didn't work. I think it's a program limitation or I'm not typing in correct syntax following the executable. In fact if I append a "--help" it runs the executable. The actual exe is spitting this error out.

Comment: Though I cannot find the original reference, several years ago I read that R does not like spaces in directories (on windows at least). Since then, I've always installed R in a space-less directory (`C:\R\R-3.3.4\...` for example). I've had no problems since then. Not a solution but a workaround, sorry.

Comment: @r2evans - This is exactly what I was thinking. People claim it works so I'm a bit confused as to how.

Comment: Found one reference: [R FAQ 2.2](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-install-R-for-Windows_003f). The point made is not definitively *"install R in a place with no spaces in the paths"*, but one could infer untestedness (??) and such from the verbiage used. I inferred, and have had no problems (which is not itself a clear indicator).

Comment: I found a solution. This occurs because 8dot3 naming convention is disabled! For anyone else having this issue, and I saw there were others, you can re-enable it but if the directory is already created then it can't easily re-create a short name for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. This occurs because 8dot3 naming convention is disabled! For anyone else having this issue, and I saw there were others, you can re-enable it but if the directory is already created then it can't easily re-create a short name for it.